# How to connect UDP Fins Gateway DotNet?

Tags: c#, .net, udp, fins

I'm trying to connect to an Omron PLC (NX1P2) that support only UDP Connections. I can't find free working libraries or examples in internet for UDP connections.

Thanks for help.

Comment: There is this open source [libfins](https://github.com/lammertb/libfins), but, besides being C, it seems to support only TCP. Some years ago I had to write my own FINS library to communicate with an Omron PLC, but I think it was TCP only too. Maybe you could adapt an existing TCP one?

Comment: there are numerous UDP examples out there - internet or no, it works the same.. what specifically are you having issues with. Post the code.

Comment: I have issues converting TCP to UDP libraries, because it's the first time for me using UDP connections. Marco, can you please send me the code that you wrote with TCP. Maybe it's better than online's.

Comment: I've not released it publicly (yet). If it may be interesting, I could release it as open source on github.

Comment: Maybe it's a good Idea. Reply here with the LINK. Thanks.